# MapGuide Maestro - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: mapguide, mapguide-maestro

I facing an issue by using MapGuide Maestro.
I installed MapGuideOpenSource 2.6.0.8316 x64 and MapGuideMaestro Release 6.0a3.
When I started MapGuide Maestro a first windows info appear and say:

[image]

I create my folder and I add my shapefile resource, double click on my layer and in order to modifed my feature representation and labels.
[image]

When I click on previous resource icon, an error message show up.
[image]

Somebody have an idea?

I found several tutorial online and look around for a solution but nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found why I had that Input String message error.

You have to go in:

Control Pane >> Region and Language >> Formats >> choose English (United States)

I think the most important thing is to have the good numbers format in order to match the app.

Only one point is that the Tooltip didn't show the name when I'm moving my mousse arrow over the symbol.

Maybe someone know?

Stéphane.